# use Data Annotation to my Linq to SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, data-annotations

i have a mvc web project and i'm using linq to sql 
i'm using dataannotaion like this

```
public class ClientValidation
{
  [Required]
  public string name1st { get; set; }
 }
```

then in the linq class i add that above client class

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name = "dbo.Client")]
[MetadataType(typeof(ClientValidation))]
public partial class Client : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
```

}

every thing is going ok
the question is when i re generate the linq when i add table or change any thing in database i need to rewrite [MetadataType(typeof(ClientValidation))]
is there any other method to enable me regenerate the model and keep the data annotation as it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a partial class in another file with empty body and just annotate that with your attribute, `partial class`es and `partial method`s designed for this situations where you want to add a functionality to an autogenerated class or method.